# How to interpolate speech marks using paste in r

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to write a SQL query using paste in r

I am trying to create a list of wildcards to search on using the CONTAINS statement in SQL (using SQL server)

The SQL statement is

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE CONTAINS (ItemNM ,'"bla*" OR "foo*" OR "batz*"')
```

I want to interpolate bla foo and batz as this list is user defined and will change. The issue I have is with all the speech marks. So far I have

```
RadiologyStudies<-paste0("ItemNM CONTAINS "'bla*' OR 'foo*' OR 'batz*'"")

paste0("SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE CONTAINS ",RadiologyStudies")
```

But no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :

```
RadiologyStudies <- paste0("ItemNM, 'bla*' OR 'foo*' OR 'batz*'")

paste0("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE CONTAINS (",RadiologyStudies, ')')
#[1] "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE CONTAINS (ItemNM, 'bla*' OR 'foo*' OR 'batz*')"
```